# Freezing on copy to and from NFS network

Tags: networking, mount, nfs, nas

i have a NAS shared on 4 ubuntus 14.04.3 LTS and 15.04, the NAS file system is NFS, the NAS Storage is made to be auto mounted on startup using fstab
FSTAB Entry:
`192.168.0.2:/nfs   /home/proboot/Desktop/mount nfs auto 0 0`

the problem i'm facing is that when i copy a big file from the NAS to the Ubuntu or vice versa the copy starts and works normally then freeze after some time even the whole ubuntu system freezes that i have to force shutdown the PC to make things work again.

please note that file copying on windows is working fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching on the INTERNET for 1 week i found that there is a problem in the mounting option of FSTAB, FSTAB should be

```
192.168.0.2:/nfs   /home/proboot/Desktop/mount nfs4_netdev auto 0 0
```

Comment: I believe that is incorrect. It should be `192.168.0.2:/nfs /home/proboot/Desktop/mount nfs _netdev,nfsvers=4 0 0`